# Win32 API - error: assigning to 'LPCSTR' from incompatible type 'const wchar_t[]'

Tags: c++, winapi, wchar-t, lpcstr

I have the following code,

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Sample Window Class";
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        wc.lpszClassName,               // Window class
        "Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The error occurs when I try to assign a value of the wrong type `'const char [20]'` to `'LPCWSTR'` like so:

```
    wc.lpszClassName = "Sample Window Class";

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I prefix a string with `L""`, the `Visual C++ compiler` will no longer complain.

On the other hand, if I try to compile the same code with `gcc` or `clang`, it works just fine,
but after I add the prefix it gives me the following error:

```
error: assigning to 'LPCSTR' (aka 'const char *') from incompatible type 'const wchar_t[20]'
```

I wonder what causes this strange behaviour, and how could I make one code compatible for all compilers?

Comment: I assume the first problem is because you use Visual Studio with a standard project, which defines macros that enables wide-character string structures and functions? Unless you add the exact same macros when building with GCC or Clang they will use the narrow character structures and functions.

Comment: use `WNDCLASSW` instead `WNDCLASS`, `CreateWindowExW` instead `CreateWindowEx` etc. or define `UNICODE`

Comment: @RbMm What exactly does #define UNICODE do? I've seen solutions with this, but I don't know how it would help in my case.

Comment: The `UNICODE` macro, when defined, tells the Windows header files to make all structures and functions to use their wide-character versions.

Comment: Normally you should write :

`wc.lpszClassName = _TEXT("Sample Window Class");`
or
`wc.lpszClassName = _T("Sample Window Class");`

and this work with unicode enabled or not.

Comment: @anathrax read [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings) on MSDN